# Change the toolbar title in UIImagePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, editing, title

I created an iPhone application which can take photos and allow the user to edit them
(moving and scaling), by setting the property `allowsEditing` to YES.

My problem is that while editing, the bar at the bottom has a too long title (in french).

[image: title of app]

So do you have any idea of how to change this text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its part of the private api that you can't access. sorry.

Comment: Right...
I've maybe found a fix. I have to set the "showsCameraControls" to NO
and add a personal toolbar to view. After that I've to re-create the editing image view...

Thank you anyway